# RBCodeHighlighting package breaks a fresh image

Tags: visualworks

I'm loading the RBCodeHighlighting package from the Cincom store and I get an error which says: "post load action caused an error. Tools.Trippy.BehaviorInspector has no binding". If I continue my image is broken and I can't open a workspace. I get a DNU in Workspace>>postBuildWith:

Anybody has any idea what's the solution?

Answer (score 0):

That means that Tools.Trippy.BehaviorInspector is not found as a class or SharedVariable in your image. If that originates in the postLoad-action than the code is basically loaded correctly, just some post-load initializations didn't work.
RBCodeHighlighting is only needed in VisualWorks 7.x, not in 8.x. In 8.x the SourceCodeEditor uses Text2 and RBCodeHighlighting doesn't work anymore with it.